# What does error c101abb9 mean when trying to download from the Marketplace

Tags: store

I was attempting to download some applications from the Marketplace on my phone (HTC Trophy on Vodafone UK) last night and kept getting the message"

> There is a problem completing your request. Try again later. Error
>   code: c101abb9

When I tried about an hour later, I was able to download without any trouble.

What does this error code mean and is there any way to fix the problem, other than just waiting an hour or so and trying again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error C101ABB9 is normally associated to streaming, where you're logged in to two places and using your Zune music pass on one; the other will get this error ([per Zune support](http://www.zune.net/en-us/support/webhelp/C101ABB9.htm)).

It may be the case that your account was locked fro whatever reason, and the Microsoft servers needed to update to reflect that.

In the past, when the store has been playing up (although, I've only see it do this on a Windows 8 device), closing the app, and relaunching it has allowed it to sort itself out.